# Best practices, fire-and-forget asynchronous classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asynchronous

I have a class whose sole purpose is to go download a specific file off the net, store it locally and then return the local path of the stored file.

I use this class based on whether I have a local copy of the file in question or not, and I sometimes call it up multiple times at the same time, if more than one file needs downloading. The way I use it is simply

```
Loader *l = [[Loader alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[l downloadFile:someFile];
[l release];
```

The thing is, in order to keep it around until it's done downloading, I am actually doing `[self retain];` in the class, then `[self autorelease];` when it's done. This feels hacky though. How do people deal with this?

Comment: I have done something similar, but I went with NSOperation and NSOperationQueue wrapped in a Singleton. This approach handles memory and threading. I start out by querying the OperationQueue if the operation is already in progress, if it is I ignore the request, this way calling it multiply times will not spawn several threads or stop a half-downloaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that `[self release]` and `[self autorelease]` feel weird, but that doesn't mean they're *wrong*.  In some situations, they can be the right thing to use (and I've used them before).

If you want to avoid them, however, you might consider making a `LoaderManager` class that simply owns the `Loader` objects until they're done loading stuff.  It'd essentially be a wrapper around an array, and you'd use it like this (or something):

```
@interface LoaderManager : NSObject {
  NSMutableSet *loaders;
}
@end
@implementation LoaderManager
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    loaders = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
  [loaders release];
  [super dealloc];
}
- (void)addLoader:(Loader *)loader {
  [loaders addObject:loader];
}
@end
```

And then your `Loader` object would do:

```
[myLoader downloadFile:someFile manager:aLoaderManager];
```

Which internally would simply invoke:

```
[aLoaderManager addLoader:self];
```

Comment: Loader manager sounds like a nice way to go around the self retaining issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under the circumstances, I think it's fine for your Loader to retain and autorelease itself. The most expedient solution might be to just add a detailed comment to your code that explains why it does what it does. The biggest problem is that Loader takes a delegate. Delegators don't usually retain their delegates in order to avoid retain cycles, but in this case it seems possible that the delegate could be deallocated before the Loader is finished downloading its file. If that happens, a crash is likely. So, if you want to continue with this fire-and-forget style, you might want to have Loader retain its delegate.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I had this issue awhile back and put in code where the delegate sent an abort message to all current "loaders" before deallocating.

Comment: Make @Dave DeLong's LoaderManager the delegate instead, and you won't have to retain the delegate. If the class that creates the Loader needs to know when the file is downloaded you could always have the LoaderManager post a notification. Or, skip the whole delegation thing altogether and just have the Loader post the notification itself.